# Problems accessing a web page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, https, automation

The only form that I found to access to this page is when I google it and click.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfC3l.png)

When I enter the page, I can see a line about the https protocol.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54S1L.png)

I guess that is what is affecting my code, but I don't know what to do in this case

```
#Libraries Scrape
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import re
import unittest

class dof():
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://dof.gob.mx")
        sleep(2)

    def test_extraction(self):
        driver = self.driver
        html= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        for noticia in html.find_all("a", {"class":"enlaces"}):
            noticia = noticia.text
            print(noticia)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

I want to bring the titles of the class 'enlaces'

Answer (score 0):

Per the screenshot and code snipper, the ChromeDriver is not set up to ignore SSL errors. This can be fixed by

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

However, the snippet above does not show why you need Selenium. Requests using the `requests` library can also provide HTML to be later parsed using BeautifulSoup.

Alternatively, you can find all elements that satisfy XPath (within the frame) using

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='enlaces']
```

-- and BeautifulSoup is no longer needed.